# how to style my image with object-fit:cover still being responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having trouble with styling a picture on a website I am designing. I want to frame a picture, getting a specific dimension that is visible and the rest invisible.  I have been working with `object-fit:cover` and `overflow: hidden`.  I am though open to all kind of suggestions.

Here is the html code for the image:

```
<div id="pgc-1397-2-0" class="panel-grid-cell">
<div id="panel-1397-2-0-0" class="so-panel widget widget_sow-image panel-first-child panel-last-child" data-index="2">
::before
<div class="so-widget-sow-image so-widget-sow-image-default-bf8d3ff3bedb">
<h3 class="widget-title">KRAGEN</h3>
<div class="sow-image-container">
<img src="http://www.ny.nordicredesigners.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/unspecified-3-31.jpeg"width="800" height="450" srcset="http://www.ny.nordicredesigners.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/unspecified-3-31-300x169.jpeg 300w, http://www.ny.nordicredesigners.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/unspecified-3-31-768x432.jpeg 768w, http://www.ny.nordicredesigners.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/unspecified-3-31.jpeg 800w" sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px" title="KRAGEN" class="so-widget-image"
</div>
</div>
```

I have used object-fit:cover before, but this time the image has so many classes, I am not sure in what constellation to use them. I am working with wordpress template so I can not change the html code.

It is important that the image is responsive - scaling in size.

Here is a link to the webpage:

```
http://www.ny.nordicredesigners.dk/
```

Here is a picture of how I want to frame the picture:

**this is how it is now:**
[image: this is how it is now]

**and this is what i want for result:**
[image: and this is what i want for result]

```
    .so-widget-sow-image-default-bf8d3ff3bedb .sow-image-container .so-widget-image { 
display: block; width: 100%; 
} 

.so-widget-image { 
width: auto; height: 100%; 
} 
img { 
height: 100%; 
width: auto; 
}
```

Comment: How does your CSS look like? What's the actual question? If you already know about `object-fit:cover`, does this mean you are looking for alternatives?

Comment: @Paul This is what my styling looks like right now:

`#pgc-1397-2-0 {
   
    display: block!important;
    padding: 0px 50px 0px 120px !important;
    height: auto!important;
        width: 300px!important;
    height: 400px !important;
    object-fit: none!important;
    overflow: hidden!important;

}
    
`

Comment: This is for the wrapper div only, what about the CSS for the image? Add all relevant CSS to your question.

Comment: @Paul  here is the CSS for the image `.so-widget-sow-image-default-bf8d3ff3bedb .sow-image-container .so-widget-image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.so-widget-image {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
} `

Comment: Well, you need to define the size of `.sow-image-container` correctly and then apply `object-fit` to the image. Could you create a fiddle? Also, I said add the CSS to the question, leaving it in the comments is not really legible.

Comment: @Paul I did crate a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q2yrqvxv/5/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q2yrqvxv/9/